# Japanese Characters storing as Question Mark in Sql Server DB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, unicode

I have a SQL Server Db on DiscountASP Server. I have created a Front End in VB.net and trying to insert the values in the Database. Its working great except when i insert some Japanese Characters, the data is stored in the form of Question Marks (???). My Fields in Database are of type nvarchar and before inserting into DB i am not encoding/decoding any strings in VB.net.

Any suggestions on how to store Japanese Characters in DB and then Retrieve them in Japanese as well?

Comment: What is the data type and collation of the column (the collation might be defaulting from table, database or server instance: use properties on the column in SQL Management Studio to see the collation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When doing your insert or update, you need to prefix your value with N at the front. e.g.

```
UPDATE thingy SET name = N'こんにちは'
```

Note that the N is before your single quote. That should fix it =)

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. Without the `N` prefix the literal gets treated as `varchar` in the databases's default collation.